# Setting the correct InvokeArg when executing Zend Framework controller in Zend_Test harness

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework

According to [this](http://www.nabble.com/forum/ViewPost.jtp?post=23729095&framed=y) mailing list discussion, the recommended way to access the application resources in a Zend MVC controller is:

```
$this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('foo');
```

This works in production (when browsing to the corresponding Web page). However, when testing a controller action containing this code with `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase`, I get:

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getResource() on a non-object in .../application/controllers/IndexController.php on line 12

Until introducing that `getInvokeArg` thing, the tests ran just fine. The question is, how can I make the “recommended” way of accessing resources work in the test harness?

Just checked: `$this->getFrontController()->getParam('bootstrap')->getResource('foo')` doesn't work either.

UPDATE: I do call the application bootstrap with `phpunit --bootstrap ./scripts/application_bootstrap.php ...` and I know it executes fine.

And there I have:

```
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap();
```

Comment: jason, it doesn't matter what I test. Just a single "dispatch" in a test case, firing up the controller action under test, will trigger the problem. Zero asserts. The controller runs fine in production, but blows up under Zend_Test/PHPUnit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** I'm sorry, I missed that part of your question the first time around (no coffee yet!). I've edited the answer.

The problem lies in that `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase` is meant to unit test controllers. It tries to use *very* few dependencies from the rest of the framework, and it does NOT automatically run/bootstrap/whatever (and is not aware of) your larger application.

Basically, `getResouce` doesn't work, because your bootstrap does not exist.

If you take a look around the `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase` you'll see that it manually sets up and uses `Zend_Controller_Front`, and initializes its own request/response objects for each test. It's attempting to be as much of a *unit test* as possible, not a functional or integration test.

To solve your problem, you have to tell the test suite *how* to bootstrap your application. There's a couple ways to achieve this.

One, you can assign a file to the public `bootstrap` property of the test class.

```
public $bootstrap = '/path/to/bootstrap/file.php'
```

This is a good option for applications using `Zend_Application`.

Or, by providing a callback to the `bootstrap` property:

```
public function setUp()
{
    // Use the 'start' method of a Bootstrap object instance:
    $bootstrap = new Bootstrap('test');
    $this->bootstrap = array($bootstrap, 'start');
    parent::setUp();
}
```

Note: It's really important to call the parent `setUp` method if you override it.

**Edit 2:** Ok, you *are* actually bootstrapping your application. So, you've done the above, and still no luck.

I would recommend overriding the `dispatch` method of the TestCase, to ensure that it is receiving the bootstrap. (This'll work for sure).

```
public function dispatch($url = null)
{
    $this->getFrontController()->setParam('bootstrap', $yourBootstrap);
    parent::dispatch($url);
}
```

Come to think of it, you could probably do that in the `setUp` as well.

This will allow the test suite to properly mimic the behaviour of a front controller constructed by `Zend_Application`. Both methods of accessing the bootstrap should work now.

Comment: The breaking code is in Zend_Controller_Action's subclass — a controller, not in a test case

Comment: Jason, I do call the bootstrap routine: phpunit --bootstrap ./scripts/application_bootstrap.php, and I'm sure it runs (by $application->bootstrap();), as all the resources are available via Zend_Registry, where I put stuff on init.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I spent hours thinking it was a problem with my test bootstrap itself. Zend_Test really needs better documentation, especially as it relates to Zend_Application.

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue when using a controller plugin that needed the bootstrap.

Basically I created an abstract class and inherited from it.

```
abstract class My_ControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    protected $application;

    public function setUp()
    {


        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');


        return parent::setUp();
    }

    public function appBootstrap()
       {

        $this->application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/config/app.ini');

        $this->application->bootstrap();

        $bootstrap = $this->application->getBootstrap();

        $front = $bootstrap->getResource('FrontController');

        $front->setParam('bootstrap', $bootstrap);

       }
}
```

Then you use as follows:

```
class MyControllerTest extends My_ControllerTestCase
{

}
```

I also logged a request to have this functionality become apart of ZF

[ZF-7373]: (http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7373) -

Leaving a comment would help to highlight this for inclusion.